# How can I accept array params inside a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm making an app where users can create and edit `Survey`s with a number of `Question`s. Instead of an `Answer` class, I am serializing the possible answers for each `Question` as an array in a column named `answers`.

My survey form accepts nested attributes for its questions. Each question then accepts an array of answers. To do this, I put square brackets after the name of the answer text fields as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170367/). However, this results in a NoMethodError in my nested form: `` undefined method `answers[]' for #<Question…> ``. I also tried doing this manually with a `text_field_tag`, but I couldn't figure out how to generate the right name attribute.

How can I properly accept the answers array inside my nested form?

---

survey.rb:

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

question.rb:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey
  serialize :answers, Array
end
```

_form.slim:

```
= form_with model: @survey do |survey_form|
  = survey_form.label :title
  = survey_form.text_field :title

  = survey_form.fields_for :questions do |question_form|
    = question_form.label :question
    = question_form.text_area :question

    - 5.times do
      = question_form.text_field "answers[]" # NoMethodError!

  = survey_form.submit
```